# How can I find the value of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f$ is a linear function such that $f(6)-f(2)=12$. Find the value of $f(2014)-f(1998)$

what I was thinking is $f(2)= f(6)-12$ and $f(2014=2*1007)$ and $f(1998=2*999)$ but I don't think that means $f(2014)=f(2)f(1007)$ right?

I'm confused on how to solve this problem, can anyone help please?

Comment: Clue is in *Linear* function - what does it mean for a function to be *Linear*?

Comment: so it means that $y=mx+b$ so I'm assuming i should find the slope but I don't know how i can since the points are $(2, f(6)-12)$ and $(6, f(6)+12)$

Comment: A linear function is one whose graph is a line.  So $f(x) = mx + b$  And we know that $4= f(6) -f(2) = (6m + b) - (2m+b) =4m$.  So what is $f(2014)-f(1998)$?

Comment: "but I don't know how i can since the points are (2,f(6)−12) and (6,f(6)+12) "  If that were true (you made a simple mistake) then the slope is $\frac {(f(6)+12)-(f(6)-12)}{6-2}$.  You can do that.  (But your points *AREN"T* $(2,f(6)-12)$ and $(6,f(6)+12)$.  The second point is $(6,f(6))$.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and intuitive hint: the function is linear, so it has constant slope. When $x$ changes from $2$ to $6$ (i.e. it increases by $4$), the function increases by $12$. So what happens when $x$ changes from $1998$ to $2014$ (i.e. it increases by $16$)?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If $ f$ is such that

$$f(x)=mx+n$$
then

$$\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=\frac{f(c)-f(d)}{c-d}$$

In your case, $n=0$ and
$$\frac{f(6)-f(2)}{6-2}=\frac{f(2014)-f(1998)}{2014-1998}$$
You can take it.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x) = mx + b$ then $f(6) - f(2) = (6m +b)-(2m+b) = 4m$.  But we know $f(6)-f(2) = 12$.

Now $f(2014) - f(1998)= (2014m + b)-(1998m + b) = 16m$.

Note: the $y$ intercept isn't necessary for the question.